# Number Starts with Zero in JavaScript,Don't want for Octal Converstion

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript if the number starts with `0` it's getting converted as *octal* during manipulation.

For example:

```
var mobileNumber = 01000;// Collecting from User Input
```

then value of the mobileNumber is `512` during manipulation.

We have a custom class for mobile number processing, I should pass '01000' to that accessor method.

Kindly suggest us solution for it.

Comment: Have you tried to cast mobileNumber to a string instead of a number?

Comment: var mobileNumber = "01000";

Comment: Please share your manipulation code.

Answer (score 1):

Use the second argument of the parseInt function:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

`parseInt('01000', 10)`